# uib-datepicker-popup not working in my angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

uib-datepicker-popup not working in my angular app, I works in other controller

```
<input ng-click="open($event, 'delivery_time_popup')" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" show-weeks="false" ng-model="purchase_order.delivery_time" is-open="delivery_time_popup" datepicker-options="dateOptions" required close-text="Close" placeholder="Select Date">
```

JS

```
$scope.open = function ($event, opened) {
        console.log(opened);
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope[opened] = true;
    };

    $scope.delivery_time_popup = false;

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };
```

Comment: what display in console?

Comment: delivery_time_popup

Comment: Try change `uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"` to `uib-datepicker-popup`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the `$scope.delivery_time_popup` value to true in the `open` function.

```
 $scope.open = function ($event, opened) {
    console.log(opened);
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope[opened] = true;

    $scope.delivery_time_popup = true; //add this
};
```

in your html change the `ng-click` to `ng-focus`

[Plnkr example](https://embed.plnkr.co/5RIcwzNUjORXaUd5zPeR/)

**HTML**

```
<input ng-focus="open($event, 'delivery_time_popup')" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" show-weeks="false" ng-model="purchase_order.delivery_time" is-open="delivery_time_popup" datepicker-options="dateOptions" required close-text="Close" placeholder="Select Date">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.open = function ($event, opened) {
    console.log(opened);
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope[opened] = true;

    $scope.delivery_time_popup = true;
};

   $scope.delivery_time_popup = false;

   $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
    };
});
```

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: first of all your ng-click is on a input  text it need to be on a button or instead of ng-click must be ng-focus

Comment: ng-focus is working but the date picker popup is not coming

Comment: check the update answer, and look the plknr example.

Comment: share your full controller and view